# Traversing files and directories using Java

Tags: java, file, directory, traversal

I have a small code wich can return the list of files under any directory.

What I need to do is get the `Directories` and `Files` under the first given directory.

This is the code I'm using.

```
    File dir = new File("C:/myDocument/myFolder");

    String[] children = dir.list();
    if (children == null) {

    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {

            String filename = children[i];
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
    }
```

Another thing is when I select the path from Windows 7, I get this `C:\myFolder\myFolder`.
If I use this path in Java I get this error `Invalide Escape sequence`
Do I have to change it to `C:/myDocument/myFolder` to get it work.

Help.

Thanks

Comment: \ is the escape character in Java, which is used to escape special characters contained within Java strings. If you wanted to include double-quotes within a Java string, you'd need to escape them, like so `String foo = "I'm \"bad\" at coming up with examples."` If you want to include a \ character in your String you need to escape it using another \ character, so your filepath would look like this: `C:\\myFolder\\myFolder`.

Comment: Everything that you're asking can be answered by simply looking at the [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with the code you've written? It looks like it should do what you've said you need it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, forward slashes are fine. They get normalized to the OS-dependent separator.

What the error tells you is that `\m` is an invalid escape sequence. Each backward slash tries to escape the following character. So if you need backward slashes in a string, use a double slash: `"c:\\myDocuments\\myFolder"`

In order to get directories and files, you use `.listFiles()` and then [`file.isDirectory()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) to check if it's a directory.

Comment: Ok, what about the first part ?

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar way to clear given folders.

```
    private static void deleteTree(File file)
    {
      if(file.isDirectory())
      {
        File afile[] = file.listFiles();
         System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getFilename);
         if(afile.length > 0)
         {
            for(int i = 0; i < afile.length; i++)
            {
               if(afile[i].isDirectory())
                  System.out.println("Directory: " + afile[i].getFilename);
                  deleteTree(afile[i]);
               else
                  System.out.println("File: " + afile[i].getFilename);
            }
         }
      } else {
       System.out.println("File: " + file.getFilename);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can misuse File.list(FilenameFilter) for file traversal, e.g:

```
// list files in dir
new File(dir).list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String file = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name;
        System.out.println(file);
        return false;
    }
});
```